# How to understand get value from map by its key in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir and have a question about the map keys. I have a map defined as below:

```
a = %{"key" => 1}
```

I am able to access the value by `a["key"]` but not `a.key`. If I define the map as `a = %{key: 1}`, then I am able to get the value by `a.key`. I wonder what the different between these two ways of declaring keys.

If I have a function which accept the key by `a["key']` and I have a map defined as `a = %{key: 1}`, how can I pass this variable to the function?

For example, I have below function:

```
def fun1(data) do
    data.key ... // access key by atom
done
```

and I have a variable data which is using string as the key. How can I pass this variable to the function?

Comment: Given your comments below it doesn't look as if you're sharing your actual code.  It's tough to answer your question without all the details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are two different types that are being used for your key.

- `%{"key" => 1}` is using a string for a key.
- `%{key: 1}` is short hand for `%{:key => 1}` which is using an atom for a key.

You can only use `map.key` syntax if you have atoms for keys.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways of accessing the values are syntatic sugar for Map.get/2 function.

So the difference between the two is that atoms are not garbage collected, and they are optimized by the erlang VM for things like pattern matching.

Strings are more general purpose, so because optimizations you should always try to use atoms as keys, if you can.

Now I don't know if I understood your last question, but a good "erlang" way of getting the key you want in that function would be:

as atom:

```
def fun1(%{key: value}) do
    value 
end
```

as string:

```
def fun1(%{"key" => value}) do
    value 
end
```

In both cases it will only enter the function if it matches the pattern, and your value will be already available inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

- `a = %{"key": 12}` used **string** as key, you can only use `a["key"]` to access.
- `a = %{key: 12}` used **atom** as key, you can use `a[:key]` or `a.key` to access.

Note, when there is no this key in the map, `a[:key]` will return `nil` while `a.key` will throw **KeyError**.

```
iex(1)> a = %{}
%{}
iex(2)> a[:not_exist]
nil
iex(3)> a.not_exist
** (SyntaxError) iex:7: syntax error before: not_exist
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def fun1(data) do
>     data.key ... // access key by atom
> done
> ```
>
> ...and I have a variable data which is using string as the key. How can I pass this variable to the function?

my.exs:

```
defmodule Stuff do

  def fun1(data) do
    data.a   #access key by atom
  end

end
```

In the shell:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> data = %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}                                                 %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

iex(2)> new_data =  Enum.into(data, %{}, fn {key, val} -> {String.to_atom(key), val} end)
%{a: 1, b: 2}

iex(3)> Stuff.fun1 new_data                                                          1   

iex(4)>
```

Comment: I would avoid suggesting the use of `String.to_atom/1`. Atoms are not garbage collected. You can either OOM the machine or overflow the atom table.

Comment: Premature opitmization, in my opinion.  Cross that bridge if you come to it.

Comment: It should at least be mentioned in the answer. It is very rare that you actually want to use that function.

Comment: what if the map is nested? Does your method support nested map?

Comment: @ZhaoYi, Instead of making stuff up as you go along, why don't you actually post a simple example that models your problem to start with--apparently a one key map is not what your data looks like.  And, no my answer doesn't support nested maps, because then `val` might be a map, and the code does nothing to `val`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value by using key

```
iex(1)> map = %{"a" => 1}
%{"a" => 1}
iex(2)> map["a"] 
1
iex(3)> map2 = %{a: 1}    
%{a: 1}
iex(4)> map2.a
1
```